# Mount network share automatically on startup

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab

I'm trying to have two network shares automatically mount upon rebooting my machine but I'm having no luck. I've read through several similar AskUbuntu questions but I can't seem to get it to mount the shares on rebooting.  This is my current configuration:

**/etc/fstab:**

```
//192.168.1.18/FileDepot    /mnt/FileDepot  cifs    credentials=/home/user1/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,sec=ntlm    0   0
//192.168.1.18/Incoming     /mnt/Incoming   cifs    credentials=/home/user1/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,sec=ntlm    0   0
```

In my home folder, I have the **.credentials** file:

```
username=user1
password=mypass
```

As I mentioned, this will not autmatically mount the shares on a reboot, but if I manually run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

it works.

I'm running Xubuntu 15.10 x64. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or missing?

ifconfig output:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ee:75:4d:ec:01  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f1200000-f1220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40169 (40.1 KB)  TX bytes:40169 (40.1 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:02:86:42:e4:06  
          inet addr:192.168.1.78  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3602:86ff:fe42:e406/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1324170 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:723204 (723.2 KB)`
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Here is some output from dmesg:

```
[    5.077816] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    5.077818] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    5.078083] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    5.078666] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    5.078836] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    5.080887] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    5.081008] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

I've tried using ethernet and no wifi, but that didn't help. I'm not sure where to go with this now.

Comment: can you give me the out put of "ifconfig" and "cat /etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: @Neil I updated the question with the information you requested.

Comment: did you rename those interfaces to wlp4s0 and enp0s25

Comment: I didn't edit them, no.  This is a clean install I did a couple days ago when 15.10 was released.

Comment: can you check if 70-persistent-net.rules file exists run "ls /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules" if it exist can you post what is in the file.

Comment: The file doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30673/discussion-between-neil-and-drohm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem on my system by adding `x-systemd.automount,` to the list of options in my fstab entry.
I was seeing the same problem with Raspbian Jessie (from Wheezy) which led me to [a forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180362).

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I'd give you an up-vote, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Hi, could you give a more comprehensive answer? In which way and how shall you edit the file `/etc/fstab`? You just add a line with `x-systemd.automount` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but don't you just need to add the `auto` option to the mount options? Of I'm not mistaken the default is `noauto`.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ah there’s your problem you need to add wlp4s0 to /etc/network/interfaces 
Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add

```
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlp4s0
```

and reboot.

you need Regenerate 70-persistent-net.rules file.

run

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

and

```
sudo udevadm trigger --action=add
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Thought that was it, but it didn't work on reboot.  I can still do sudo mount -a and it will mount the shares without error.  I just can't get it to mount on startup.

Comment: No change after reboot.  What does that command actually do?

Comment: it  Regenerates 70-persistent-net.rules file that file gives your interface name for your NIC's.

Answer (score 0):

The system will attempt to mount everything in `/etc/fstab` before networking comes up. This will cause mounting of the network shares to fail. You can add `_netdev` to the options of your network mounts to tell the system to only try mounting them after networking is available. Like this:

```
//192.168.1.18/FileDepot    /mnt/FileDepot  cifs    credentials=/home/user1/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,sec=ntlm,_netdev    0   0
//192.168.1.18/Incoming     /mnt/Incoming   cifs    credentials=/home/user1/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,sec=ntlm,_netdev    0   0
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't mount.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an encrypted `$HOME`? If so, it's NOT mounted at boot time. Try placong your `credentials=` files on some directory that IS available at boot time.

Comment: I didn't explicitly ask for my home folder to be encrypted so I don't believe it is.  I also tried specifying username and password in /etc/fstab to bypass having it look for the file and it still doesn't mount on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to apply to NFS as well as Samba. [A bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1515446) has been logged for  NFS shares and I'm seeing the same behaviour with either type.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the gigolo package using Synaptic or "Software Manager" (or just use the command `sudo apt install gigolo` on your Debian based distro.) It's nice if you don't want to do manual scripting (more MS windows OS like). If you have it auto connect and startup on your profile it feels more like saved network places in MS Windows OS's. Project home page https://www.uvena.de/gigolo/ for details.

Comment: Please be a little careful about using Copy and Paste answers across Ask Ubuntu particularly when you are giving a link to a particular application...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234540)